# Cannot connect Salesforce Visual Studio Editor

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I'm trying to connect one of my Sandboxes to VS however I keep getting the type error found below.

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'underline' of 'chalk_1.default' as it is undefined.
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

I've tried creating a new Java Runtime path, reinstalled VS, java 8/11/17/18 (found out VS is not compatible with java 18), and the Salesforce Extension pack. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For issues like this, you need to interact with the developers of the Salesforce VS Code app on github instead : https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1021

Comment: Got it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing 32-bit of SFDX CLI. It should resolve the issue.
PS this is just a workaround and not a fix.

Before this please make sure you're on the latest CLI version and your extensions are updated.